# Am I using the round function correctly?

Tags: perl

Here is my Perl code

```
use POSIX;

my @arr = split(/\\n\\n/, $content);

my $len = length @arr;

$len = $len / 2;

my $b = round($len) - 1;
```

At the top of my script I have `use POSIX`. I once had `use Math::Round` but that didn't work.

I'm trying to use the `round` function but the page keeps breaking when I call it.

Comment: Try this `$b = sprintf "%.0f", $len`.

Comment: What is the question? What is `$content`? What problem are you seeing?

Comment: @Borodin $content is the article content. i pass it through the split against two new lines. whats weird is i think my split on new lines is the problem.

Comment: @redneb does that turn into an integer? is there documentation on the %.0f part

Comment: `%.0f` means print a floating point number with 0 digits after the decimal point. If there are more digits, the number will be rounded. See the documentation of [sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html).

Comment: `my $len = length @arr;` is surely wrong. (It's sets `$len` to the number of digits in the size of the array.) You want `my $len = @arr;`

Comment: Re "*the page keeps breaking when I call it*", What error are you getting?

Comment: Indeed, regarding *"the page keeps breaking when I call it"*. Are you writing a network application? What is the ***page*** that you speak of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what you're hoping to do, but it's looking like you have a variable `$content` that is the result of a previous operation

You think that data is structured in blocks with a blank line between the blocks, so you're splitting on the four-character sequence `\n\n` to put a block into each element of array `@arr`

(Please don't call arrays `@arr`. The `@` says it's an array and adding `arr` to that is pointless. The following characters are an opportunity for you to explain the nature of the data that your array contains, and it's a very valuable opportunity. I have no idea what your data contains: it may be the dates of the next two Sundays, or the number of the next lottery ticket. `@arr` says nothing at all.)

In reality there are probably only two linefeed characters between the blocks, so `@arr` will contain the entirety of `$content` in a single element `$arr[0]`

The rest of your code looks like

```
my $len = length @arr;

$len = $len / 2;

my $b = round($len) - 1;
```

I imagine you expect `$len` to be set to the number of elements in `@arr`. You do that by writing `my $len = @arr`. What you have written does something entirely different

Then you want to halve whatever `$len` was set to, round it and subtract one

This is looking like you're aiming to do something like a *merge sort*, and you need to split the array into two halves and process them recursively

If I'm right, then `$len` will now be either an integer or an integer plus 0.5, and invoking `POSIX::round` is no better than a simple `int`

I've now made so many guesses that it's pointless to continue. If you explain your overall purpose then we will be able to help you much better

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you are using the `length` function incorrectly.

`length @arr` does not return the size of array `@arr` as you might expect, it just returns the length of the size of `@arr`. To get the array length, you want to use `scalar @arr` or to "evaluate `@arr` in scalar context":

```
$len = scalar @arr;
$len = @arr;           # assignment to scalar is "scalar context"
```

---

It's also not clear if you're using `split` correctly.

```
@arr = split /\\n\\n/, $content
```

splits on the literal string `\n\n`. If you want to split `$content` wherever there are consecutive newlines, you just want to say

```
@arr = split /\n\n/, $content
```

Comment: **ikegami** has already said *"`my $len = length @arr;` is surely wrong. (It's sets `$len` to the number of digits in the size of the array.) You want `my $len = @arr;`"* [in the comments above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39397702/am-i-using-the-round-function-correctly/39398672#comment66121794_39397702). In any case I don't see how this is a solution to the question.